# Read() / Readline() UnicodeDecode Error in same column location over .txt file Directory

Tags: python

I have a directory of .txt files

Each .txt file has the same formatting and I am only interested in a specific column range, of the first line, of each .txt file in the directory.

I've attempted using read(150 - 139), where those numbers represent the column range I am interested in, and readline().

The problem encountered with read(150 - 139) is that it outputs the entire .txt file or throws the UnicodeDecodeError.

The problem encountered with readline() is that it throws the UnicodeDecodeError.

PLEASE NOTE: The column range of each .txt file in the directory are readable characters, ANSI encoding for each file. [Mud, Sample, Resistivity, Neutron, or Gamma].

OBJECTIVE: Append the characters, at the same column range, across all .txt files within the directory to a list --> lst_2

**Code:**

```
import os
#import numpy as np


#A string array containing all file names in a directory
names = os.listdir('c:\\users\Admin\Documents\Exm_3')
lst=[]
lst_2=[]


for name in names:

    if name.endswith(".txt"):

        lst.append(name)# append the names

        with open(os.path.join('c:\\users\Admin\Documents\Exm_3', name)) as file:

            c = file.read(150 - 139)
            lst_2.append(c)

print(lst)
print(lst_2)
```

**Output:**

```
['j.txt', 'n.txt', 'q.txt', 'test.txt', 'y.txt']

['A2D 3.1.0 C', 'A2D 3.1.0 C', 'A2D 3.1.0 C', '           ', 'A2D 3.1.0 C']

A2D 3.1.0.C represents the range [0 - 10], not [139 - 150]
```

Comment: The problem with `read(150 - 139)` is that `150 - 139` is 11, so you’re just asking it to read 11 bytes from the current position. If you want to read the 11 bytes starting at position 139 in the file, you have to `file.seek(139)` first.

Comment: But your more fundamental problem is that you’re trying to read the file as a UTF-8 text file when it clearly isn’t one. If you know what encoding the file is in, and the value you want is at _characters_ 139 to 150, then you can open the file with the right encoding, then slice it. If you don’t know what encoding the file is in, and the value you want is at _bytes_ 139 to 150, you can open the file in binary mode, seek to 139, read the bytes, and decode them as ASCII. If you don’t know what the encoding is, but you need characters rather than bytes, your problem is impossible.

Comment: When you say “ANSI encoding”, what do you mean? If you mean they’re stored in your current Windows system’s OEM codepage, like cp1252 or something, then just specify that as the `encoding` when opening the file.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. The encoding of the files is ASCII, I am using Python 3, and need the location of the characters starting at the index 139 to 150.